# wireshark problem while loading or opening wireshark qt.qpa.plugin

Tags: qt, wireshark

```
av_acharya@AnoxBotox:/$ wireshark
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "path/to/plugins"
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.


sudo apt-get install --reinstall qt5-default
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  qt5-default
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/24.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 170 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package qt5-default:amd64.
(Reading database ... 241279 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../qt5-default_5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking qt5-default:amd64 (5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
```

Comment: Please provide OS/release details.  (your paste implies one release, but if your release is something different - the assumption made on detail provided is your problem as currently we don't know).

Comment: can youtell me  how to do please tell the code im new in ubuntu @guiverc

Comment: `lsb_release -a` will provide details  (your package in the paste was a *focal* package, but for us to assume that's your release implies that's not your problem.. Knowing that detail highlights that is valid, plus that source is good.. ie. crossing off potential problems..; ie. I compared with https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=qt5-default)

Comment: @guiverc if you are asking for this then here it is 'av_acharya@AnoxBotox:/$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal'

Comment: @guiverc i opened the page and im there in File list of package qt5-default in focal of architecture amd64 now what to do

Comment: I added that link only for FYI purposes (ie. learning and understanding on my comments/questions), if your package didn't answer your 20.04/focal response you've got the problem, if the package version didn't match what it should be again issues (with sources). etc.  I rarely use `wireshark` & haven't had issues with it so can't help with your issue..  (working on my lubuntu)

Comment: sorry but whtats the solution now what should i do i am really sry to irritate you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i have downloaded qt-everywhere-src-5.15.0 how to install or use it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270687/i-have-downloaded-qt-everywhere-src-5-15-0-how-to-install-or-use-it)