# i have downloaded qt-everywhere-src-5.15.0 how to install or use it

Tags: package-management, software-installation, qt, qt5

This downloaded file is in my download folder. Where should I keep this folder and how to use and install it?

Previously I deleted all qt5 files show there is an error so I have downloaded it.

I have extracted the `tar.gz` file but I need to know in detail what to do with this offline installer.

This error was occurring as I deleted all files of qt5

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: please always add the actual command to a question. If you issued only a command I would assume you are not feeding it a parameter

Comment: i was trying to run 'wireshark' @Rinzwind

Answer (score 0):

> Where should I keep this folder and how to use and install it?

tar.gz should go to /opt/ IF intended for every user on the system or in your home into a dedicated directory if for 1 single user.

> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""
> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized.
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

You need to set `export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` before starting to enable debugging and track the errors or the notices it shows. But the notice has an interesting bit: `"xcb" in ""` The last "" is an indication some setting is NOT set.

Comment: thanks for the reply can you please help me with the command and how to place i am beginner can you please tell little more in details thanks for help @Rinzwind